# Strange redirect text in page cache entries

Tags: 7

My Drupal site is having some redirect malware issues. I suspected some strange redirects and tried to catch redirects by caching them through Nginx. Below is the output of one redirect.

Page https://www.test.com/officialsite doesn't exist on the site. No URL redirect with this value.

However, visiting https://www.test.com/officialsite produces a redirect loop because it leads back to Nginx instead of hitting Drupal which would have possibly redirected it elsewhere as a result of malware.

What I have done:

- Checked all files (no changes - we manage the codebase via a Git repository)
- Checked Variables and System Tables and can't find anything unless I am not looking for correct
- Running Drupal 7 up to date

And running out of ideas!

---

Sorry can't enclose it in code as it loses formatting.

^E^@^@^@^@^@^@^@¯Ô d^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ/à<9c>d^@^@^@^@<8b>Ù¾B^@^@g^AJ^B^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
KEY: /officialsiteGET
^A^F^@^A^@Û^E^@Status: 301 Moved Permanently^M
X-Drupal-Cache: HIT^M
Link: https://www.test.com/officialsite; rel="canonical"^M
Location: [https://www.test.com/officialsite^M](https://www.test.com/officialsite%5EM)
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8^M
^M

Comment: My guess is your site has been hacked and the malicous code is trying to redirect your users elsewhere. If your code is in a git repository doing a "git diff" on the live server will likely show lots of altered code

Comment: Looks pretty hacked to myself as well.

Comment: Are you sure? Is it not gzipped?